# Count unique items on a list that meet multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This sounds simple, but I'm getting a real headache trying to figure it out:

I have two tables in excel in the same workbook but on different sheets. I want to count unique items in column B on the first table that meet a criteria (based on the data that's in column A of that table) and appear on the second table (on a different worksheet).

Because the data I'm working with is confidential, I've made up the two tables below (I've just clipped .jpgs). They are similarly formatted, but in reality I have much more data.

I need a formula that counts the number of unique people in Column B of Table 1 who also appear in Column B of Table 2 *and* whose date (in Column A of Table 1) is on or before 4/2/2016.

In this example it should come out with the answer three (for Bob, Jim, and Sue).

**Table 1**

[image: Table 1]

**Table 2**

[image: Table 1]

Any help you can provide would be hugely appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put this `=IF(AND(COUNTIF('Second Table'!$B:$B,'First Table'!$B2)>0,$A2<DATE(2016,4,2),SUMIF(B1:$B1,B2,$C$1:$C1)=0),1,"")` in `C2`, then auto-fill it down would do it and you could sum it then at the bottom..

Comment: Hmmm... this is a neat idea--I thought I'd have to use a table array or something. Unfortunately this formula isn't working on my spreadsheet :( The first line returns a 1, but subsequent lines are blank.

Comment: There should be blanks (except for Bob, Jim, and Sue) - are you getting 1 alongside Jim and Sue? (I did)

Comment: I get a 1 next to the first line, but not next to any subsequent lines, and there are definitely lots of people who appear in both lists.